How to configure PHP cache headers to prevent unnecessary browser requests
Right now a request is always made, which is then answered with 304 Not modified, but it would be better if the browser did not make a request at all. How do I achieve this, which headers to send, etc.? I can't seem to figure it out.
I couldn't find a solution to my question so here I am.
The current code I have which I put images through to add them to cache is:
$location = base64_decode($_GET['location']);
$path = path($location);


header('X-Sendfile: ' . $path);
header('Content-type: ' . mime_content_type($path));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');

header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=' . 60 * 60 * 24);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 60 * 60 * 24) . ' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', filemtime($path)));
header('Etag: "' . md5_file($path) . '"');

if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) >= filemtime($path)) ||
    (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) && trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) === $etag)
) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 304');
    exit();
}

readfile($path);

What I've tried: I've looked everywhere on Google, stackoverflow, other web forums, youtube, experimenting with it myself.
What I'm expecting: Right now a request is always made, which is then answered with 304 Not modified, but it would be better if the browser did not make a request at all.
Result right now: It gives me a 304 Not Modified status code.
Any help is appreciated!
This is my first question on here, so if you need more information I will try to give as much as I can.

Whether to honor caching policies depends on your browser and its settings. Anyway these headers work for my Edge and Firefox.

What does path() do?

path() is a helper function that gives back an base64 encoded path url
function url(string $location): string
{
    global $config;

    $location = trim($location, "/ \n\r\t\v\x00");
    return "{$config->base_url}/file.php?location=" . urlencode(base64_encode($location));
}

function path(string $location): string
{
    global $config;

    if (str_contains($location, $config->file_path)) {
        return $location;
    }

    $location = trim($location, "/ \n\r\t\v\x00");
    return "{$config->file_path}/{$location}";
}


Beware that an arbitrary file can be downloaded by using ../../some_dir/some_file in the location parameter.

That shouldn't happen as the image url will become something similar like: localhost:XXXX/file.php?location=fOgrseDOgAOEJFgoibNEIDFGHRGRSON
So would that still be a vulnerability in this case?

An attacker can use any URL they want, so, yes, the code is vulnerable.

Just because you encode the location doesn't prevent someone from entering any location they please to start with.  Base64 encoding is not exactly a secret, and it's pretty easy to spot once you have seen a few examples. So someone could encode a path value themselves, stick it into your URL, and have the webserver return pretty much any file on the system.  Your script ought to check the path provided and make sure it's within an area you are happy for users to download things from

Okay thanks for the information i will check it out later, but I would also like an answer to my actual question.

Ok. But we need a bit more detail I think. You say Right now a request is always made...do you literally mean always, even if the cache-control timer has not expired? That would suggest that caching is simply disabled in your browser.

What I meant with that was that a 304 response is made and what I want is to not send that request in the first place if it's not needed.

That doesn't answer my very specific question. If the browser has first requested the resource, and been given that, and given the cache-control header, then - if caching is enabled in the browser for that site -  it shouldn't send a fresh request for the resource until the time specified in the cache-control has expired. If it's sending one within the cache time, then most likely caching is disabled in the browser.

But if it's sending the request after the cache control time has expired, then that's normal behaviour. How else do you expect the browser to know whether it needs to refresh the data? It has no idea whether a file on the server has been modified or not - the only way it can find out is to ask the server. Your code is sensible though in that respect: if the resource hasn't changed, it will send a 304 response instead of downloading it again...this will save you time, CPU and bandwidth.

function set_cache($period=3600){
    if($period==0){
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",1);
        header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT",1);
    }else{
        header_remove('Expires');
        header_remove('Pragma');
        header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=$period",1);
        header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$period).' GMT', 1);
    }
}

My clients never send request with such code until expiration period. The only way - clear browser cache or check "No cache" in browser's developer tools

Thank you! I did already fixed it by changing the order in which I had the headers, No idea why it didn't before when I changed the order, but thanks!
